# Complex Query in Query Builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I execute this query using QueryBuilder in Symfony 2

```
SELECT um.id, sv.patentgroup_id, pm.portfolio_id, pp.id
FROM sv_patents sv
LEFT JOIN pm_patentgroups pm ON sv.patentgroup_id = pm.id
LEFT JOIN pm_portfolios pp ON pm.portfolio_id = pp.id
LEFT JOIN um_users um ON pp.user_id
```

The associations in entity classes are defined as

In SvPatents I have

```
 /**
 * @var PmPatentgroups
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PmPatentgroups")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="patentgroup_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $patentgroup;
```

In PmPatentgroups I have

```
/**
 * @var PmPortfolios
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PmPortfolios")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="portfolio_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $portfolio_id;
```

In PmPortfolios I have

```
/**
 * @var UmUsers
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UmUsers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

I tried this but it is giving me the whole results from the table looks like joins are not working propoerly

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:SvPatents');
        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('sv')
        ->leftJoin('sv.patentgroup','pm')
        ->leftJoin('pm.portfolio_id','pp')
        ->leftJoin('pp.user','um')
        ->getQuery();
        $patents = $qb->getArrayResult();
```

I am quite new to Symfony2 and Doctorine2. I read the whole documentation but could not find such complex example actually i am bit confused with how the querybuilder build the query. It would be great if you explain it a little in simple words

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. If u looks for the records of a specific user in the table then you need to add one where clause. This is how your query should looks like

```
$user_id = 1;
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:SvPatents');
        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('sv')
        ->select('sv')
        ->leftJoin('sv.patentgroup','pm')
        ->leftJoin('pm.portfolio_id','pp')
        ->leftJoin('pp.user','um')
        ->where('pp.user = :user_id')
        ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
        ->getQuery();
        $patents = $qb->getArrayResult();
```

Thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. You just have to add a `->select()` query part:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:SvPatents');
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('sv')
                 ->select('um.id, pm.id, pp.id') // add this part
                 ->leftJoin('sv.patentgroup','pm')
                 ->leftJoin('pm.portfolio_id','pp')
                 ->leftJoin('pp.user','um')
                 ->getQuery();
$patents = $qb->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: after adding the select it gave the ids of only sv_ptents table and again whole records kindly look at the sql on the top what i need to retrieve

Comment: Actually I was looking for a specific user records and for That i need to add one where clause after all the left joins That worked for me

Comment: Should I upload the correct query as answer or edit my question with correct query

Comment: Usually I find that people respond to their own question.